# Tried to implement a random forest using r got an error

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

The error that i got is

> Warning message:
>   In randomForest.default(m, y, ...) :
>   The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?

What may be the reason for this?

The code that i used is:

```
data = read.csv("C:/Users/VIJAY/Desktop/ML/logistic regression/diabetes.csv") 
head(data)
dim(data)

set.seed(1000)

train = sample(1:nrow(data),460)
train$Outcome = factor(train$Outcome)
head(train)

**model = randomForest(Outcome ~.,data = data,subset = train)** # i got eroor running this part
```

The head of the data i used for implementing the model is given below. The model has 768 rows

```
Pregnancies Glucose BloodPressure SkinThickness Insulin  BMI DiabetesPedigreeFunction Age Outcome
1           6     148            72            35       0 33.6                    0.627  50       1
2           1      85            66            29       0 26.6                    0.351  31       0
3           8     183            64             0       0 23.3                    0.672  32       1
4           1      89            66            23      94 28.1                    0.167  21       0
5           0     137            40            35     168 43.1                    2.288  33       1
6           5     116            74             0       0 25.6                    0.201  30       0
```

Comment: Could you write more about the package you are using and provide a reproducible example of your code?

Comment: It's a warning, rather than an error. It's difficult to be certain without seeing the code your ran, but probably you have a numeric outcome variable that has fewer than five unique values. For example, you get that warning if you do, `randomForest(cyl ~ ., data=mtcars)`, because `cyl` is numeric, so `randomForest` does regression (rather than classification), but you get the warning, because `cyl` has only three unique values.

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. It's telling you that there are too few unique values to run regression. Perhaps you want to do classification, in which case the outcome variable should be a factor? It would help to see your code.

Comment: @neilfws i have included the code

Comment: Probably you want to make `Outcome` a factor **in `data`**, not in `train`, since `train` is just a vector of indices. Change `train$Outcome = factor(train$Outcome)` to `data$Outcome = factor(data$Outcome)`. (Voting to close as typo)